# Trouble using spring-data-solr with Broadleaf commerce

Tags: broadleaf-commerce, spring-data-solr

Using Broadleaf Commerce version 5.2.2-GA. I have implemented custom search capability using spring-data-solr.

Seeing this issue:

```
[org.broadleafcommerce.cms.url.domain.URLHandlerImpl]
are managed classes within the MergePersistenceUnitManager
but were not detected as being transformed by the EntityMarkerClassTransformer. There can be multiple causes for this:
1. Session persistence is enabled in your servlet container (like Tomcat) and an entity object has been loaded by the container before being loaded by the application's classloader. Ensure that session persistence is disabled; in Tomcat ensure that a <Manager pathname="" /> element exists in your context.xml.
2. You are inadvertently using class scanning to find a ServletContainerInitializer class, and your servlet container is loading all classes before transformers have been registered. If you are using a web.xml, ensure that there is an <absolute-ordering /> element somewhere in that file. If you are not using a web.xml and are using Spring Boot, then you likely need to add one. See https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/5.2/broadleaf-concepts/key-aspects-and-configuration/app-server-configuration/tomcat for the example web.xml
3. The classes are being used as apart of an @Bean method or in some other runtime capacity that is initialized prior to persistence manager startup
```

I can get around the error by either:

1. removing spring-instrument.jar, via site/pom.xml overriding spring-boot-maven-plugin config:

```xml
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration combine.self="override">
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```

2. Removing 'specifically' the spring-data-solr dependency (just to prove it causes the error), i.e. from core/pom.xml, removing this:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I am happy to remove instrumentation for the time being, although this causes issues with the Auditing functionality. I.e. when attempting to save a BLC organic entity (such as StaticAssetImpl), due to the fact spring-instrumentation is not available, I see this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.broadleafcommerce.common.audit.AbstractAuditableListener.setAuditData(AbstractAuditableListener.java:88)
```

Ideally in the longer term, I would like to safely be able to include the spring-data-solr dependency. NOTE: I can safely use spring-data-commons and spring-data-jpa, it appears that spring-data-solr is solely causing the issue. I have tried spring-data-solr 3.0.5.RELEASE, 3.0.8.RELEASE (latest) and 2.0.9.RELEASE.

In the meantime, have been looking for a way to disable Auditing, cant seem to find any documentation. I have tried overriding Entities to remove the @EntityListener, tried to override the AdminAuditableListener, tried to look for a property that would disable it but no luck as yet.

Appreciate any help with either a short term workaround to disable Auditing, disable Auditing for specific Entities only or perhaps something I have not tried that could make spring-data-solr compatible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error you are running into regarding `UrlHandlerImpl` was resolved in Broadleaf 5.2.3-GA, see https://github.com/broadleafcommerce/issues/issues/5. The latest Broadleaf release is actually 5.2.6-GA.

There might be something inadvertent (scanning or something) that Spring Data Solr adds, but generally this piece shouldn't be an issue.